# When "blank" is closed, do "this"

Tags: batch-file

i'm very new to coding and was wondering if there is a command that can tell the file to execute something if the file is closed. I would prefer it if you did not implement the new code into the code I give you, because I think it is better to learn by experience. Just telling me the commands would be perfect. So for example; here is a "Matrix Code" copied from online:

```
@echo off
color 02
:start
echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%
goto start
```

What is a command that would tell it to do an action once the program is closed, like reopen.

Comment: What's "the file" that's closed? The running batch file? Some random text file?

Comment: If there was a way to allow a program to reopen itself once closed, then that can be quite abused and a security flaw, think spyware, viruses, malware, etc.

Comment: Yes it is the running batch file. Would it even be possible to make it execute a command if it were to be closed?

Comment: Ok Jordan, So you do not believe that this would be possible? Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: You can generate another bat within the first one, who test the PID of the first process, and if it don't find the PID of the first process then it start it again.

Comment: To the OP: do you want to rerun a batch file after it is done, or rerun a batch file if someone clicks the close X icon?

Comment: Rerun a batch file after it is closed, not done.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
start /w (name of file)
```

Opens a file and then waits for it to close before moving on. 
If the file that is open is called "matrix.bat" for example, then you use

```
@echo off
start /w matrix.bat
start matrix.bat
```

This will start matrix.bat which will do the matrix and then when it is closed, it restarts matrix.bat. 
This code requires 2 batch windows to be open at the same time though.

*Note: if you are using windows XP or lower, it requires /wait instead of /w.*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any native commands that are designed to achieve this outcome.
However, given Batch programs can be used to create and start other scripting languages, you do have the option of having your batch make a Vbs process monitor to see when cmd.exe is closed and then start another batch of your choosing (or restart the same batch). For this to work smoothly, be sure to have steps in place to end the vbs script in order to avoid an endless loop.

```
::: Place this code at the start of any Batch, and it will make a vbs that continuously reopens the target .Bat script when
::: there's no CMD windows open.
::: ECHO WshShell.run "%~dpnx0", 0, true REM Change to "ECHO WshShell.run "%~dpnx0", 0, true" to make your Batch Invisible.
::: To change the .bat program run when your batch is closed, replace "%~dpnx0" with the full path of the other program to run.

(
ECHO Set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:"^)
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^)
ECHO DO while proc.count ^> 0
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^)
ECHO if proc.count ^< 1 then exit do
ECHO wscript.sleep 1500
ECHO loop
ECHO Set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell"^)
ECHO WshShell.run "%~dpnx0",1, true
)>"%TEMP%\ReAnimator.vbs"

START "" "%TEMP%\ReAnimator.vbs"

:main & REM your batch script below


:EOF & REM Cleanup to cancel the vbs script when script is exited properly
    taskkill /pid WScript.exe /f /t >nul
    Timeout 1 >nul
    Del /F "%TEMP%\ReAnimator.vbs"
    Exit /B
```

- The vbs script calls to WMIService for a process count on cmd.exe and holds itself in a loop so long as the count is GEQ 1
- Sleep is used within the loop to space out calls to the WMI service, as doing so is exceptionally resource intensive
- Once the condition is met for the loop to break, it spawns a shell instance of cmd.exe running the batchfile at the path used to create the script.